In C++ are all subexpressions of function call arguments sequenced consistently?
Consider a situation where we have the following functions:
// A function with two parameters.
void AcceptTwoInts(int, int);

// Two functions that accept an integer and return another integer.
int Foo(int);
int Bar(int);

// Two functions that produce some integer.
int Baz();
int Qux();

Further, consider this function call expression:
AcceptTwoInts(Foo(Baz()), Bar(Qux()));

My question: Is the call to Baz sequenced (even indeterminately) with respect to the call to Qux? I'm wondering if I can assume anything about whether all subexpressions for one argument have been evaluated by the time we start evaluating subexpressions for another argument, regardless of which order the compiler chooses for those two arguments.
(I don't care about the "as if" rule here; I'm talking about situations where I can tell the difference.)

The reason I wonder if there might be some guarantee is this sentence in [expr.call]/7:

The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter.

The wording seems ambiguous here; it seems to me it can be interpreted in two ways:

The way that gives me a guarantee: given arguments A and B, either all subexpressions associated with A are sequenced before all subexpressions associated with B or vice versa.

The way that gives me no guarantee: just the initialization step for A and the initialization step for B are indeterminately sequenced, not any of the subexpressions that go into that initialization.


Which one is the correct interpretation? In other words, is the call to Baz a "value computation" with respect to initializing first parameter for AcceptTwoInts?

For me the sentence is pretty clear: [...]including every associated value computation[...] so the correct interpretation is the number 1.

I think this has not changed since C++17, but since you specifically tagged C++23, I'll leave it to someone else to confirm. The C++17 version of this question is What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?

Note clang sequence this call differently then gcc and msvc: https://godbolt.org/z/K4EzbTn86 On clang it is Baz Foo Qux Bar AcceptTwoInts and for gcc and msvc it is:  Qux Bar Baz Foo AcceptTwoInts

This was clarified by CWG2599. In C++23, [dcl.init.general]/19 reads:

Initialization includes the evaluation of all subexpressions of each initializer-clause of the initializer (possibly nested within braced-init-lists) and the creation of any temporary objects for function arguments or return values.

Thus the call to Baz is indeed indeterminately sequenced with the call to Qux.

The quote you mentioned from the standard is quite explicit:

The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter.

Emphasis mine
So in your example:
AcceptTwoInts(Foo(Baz()), Bar(Qux()));

Baz() is an associated computation of the call to Foo(). Respectively, Qux() is an associated computation of the call to Bar().
And all of them are associated computations of the call to AcceptTwoInts().
In other words:

if Foo() is sequenced before Bar(), then we would have the following call order:

Baz() --> Foo() --> Qux() --> Bar() --> AcceptTowInts()


if Bar() is sequenced before Foo(), then we would have the following call order:

Qux() --> Bar() --> Baz() --> Foo() --> AcceptTwoInts()


Thanks, yeah, that's the first interpretation I mentioned. But the wording is not fully clear to me: "initialization" is a specific term of art in the standard, and the call to Qux is not directly part of the initialization. I feel like this could have been clearer, like saying "and evaluation of all inputs to that initialization".

@jacobsa: What else could "every associated value computation and side effect" possibly mean? What other kinds of associations are there to initialization than the sub-expressions that are used to initialize something?

@NicolBolas thank you for your polite contribution. You can see from duck's answer that not only was I not the only person who was unsure about the wording, but the committee itself agreed the wording could be firmed up.

My question comes down to asking what an "associated value computation" is when speaking of initializing a function parameter. This terminology is used all over the place in the standard when defining order of evaluation, so I guess we must assume it means something like "evaluation of any subexpression".
I still can't find a perfectly matching formal definition in the standard, but it seems [expr.1]/1 comes close by noting what an expression is:

Note 1: […] An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies a computation. An expression can result in a value and can cause side effects.

So it seems clear the intended interpretation is the first one: everything associated with argument A is sequenced before everything associated with argument B, but which is A and which is B is unspecified.

Historical notes
Looking back at P0145R3, which was the paper that originally got this rule into the standard, I feel the original wording is clearer about the intent:

Every value computation and side effect associated with the initialization of a parameter, and the initialization itself, is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the initialization
of any subsequent parameter.

Including "and the initialization itself" makes it clearer that the associated value computations are not e.g. just computations in the constructor for the parameter, but rather can be inputs to the initialization of that parameter. This still could be better by defining the term rigorously, but it's something.
Note however that this is a much stronger guarantee than what we actually have today, since it guarantees left to right ordering. The wording was changed in this commit, associated with P0400R0. Disappointingly that paper doesn't give any motivation for the change. And the "before" wording is not correct, although it's even clearer about the intent (emphasis mine):

The initializations of the declared parameters are indeterminately sequenced with no interleaving.

That is the alternate wording that provides no gaurantee on argument evaluation order from P0145R3 section 8, which the paper says was rejected. I guess something changed afterward, and the committee decided to go that route, and then tweaked the wording again afterward.
